# FANMOD - Subgraph search using Hadoop/MapReduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata, subgraph

I have this [Fanmod](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDYQygQwAQ&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_motif#ESU_.28FANMOD.29&ei=5TInU9XlLoP_iAftkoDYDQ&usg=AFQjCNGdx6cdYLFi91NQI-cW-p6VFZjmCQ&sig2=y4rFqQdl49ao9_J0SObG1Q&bvm=bv.62922401,d.aGc)
 algorithm which I am supposed to implement for big data.

I was wondering if it would be efficient to do it with Hadoop/Mapreduce.

If not, then could you please give me some tips on efficiently solving this problem?

Comment: It would be better if you first try to solve it by yourself and then ask for help, stating the problems that you faced.

Comment: The reason I provided the link to the problem is that according to posts on the web applicability of MR depends on problem formulation and so I gave attached it. 
From what I understand it is an iterative problem and according to what I've found MR is not the best option for these kinds of problems. I just wanted to make sure if that's true.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably already familiar with [SAHAD Subgraph Analysis in Massive Networks Using Hadoop](http://staff.vbi.vt.edu/maleq/papers/ipdps12.pdf), in which they have performed network motif analysis successfully using Hadoop.

It's not quite accurate to say that Hadoop cannot perform iterative processing ... just that it's more difficult in Hadoop.  I would recommend reading this link: [Iterative Algorithms in Hadoop](http://gdfm.me/2011/06/10/iterative-algorithms-in-hadoop/) for more information, but in a nutshell, iterative processing in Hadoop require chaining jobs together back to back.

Based on your requirement (subgraph search), this seems like a reasonable use case for using the Hadoop and MR framework.

Alternatively, if you need constant iterative processing and MR isn't cutting it, you could use Storm on Hadoop HDFS.